# Warum wird “daist” in Schopenhauers Werk zusammengeschrieben?

Tags: spelling, compound

[Hier](https://books.google.ch/books?id=V7tCDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=als%20vorstellung%20daist&source=bl&ots=oc3Ii3InzV&sig=D7rD1did3zJLXYJ5z3oPNMbYG24&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT5_Krsf3WAhVFcBoKHQJ9CgcQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=als%20vorstellung%20daist&f=false) fand ich zweimal auf derselben Seite, dass *da ist* zusammengeschrieben wurde, also *daist.* Da es zweimal auf der gleichen Seite ist, schließe ich einen Tippfehler aus.

Will Schopenhauer hier betonen, dass er mit *daist* wirklich das Dasein im philosophischen Sinne meint?
Oder hatte man tatsächlich in seinen Zeiten (1788–1860) *dasein* als ein Verb betrachtet, wobei *da* als eine Vorsilbe galt?

Selbst im Wörterbuch von Grimm finde ich *Dasein* nur als Nomen.

---

Die zwei erwähnten Textstellen:

> Es wird ihm dann deutlich und gewiß, daß er keine Sonne kennt und keine Erde; sondern immer nur ein Auge, das eine Sonne sieht, eine Hand, die
>   eine Erde fühlt; daß die Welt, welche ihn umgiebt, nur als Vorstellung
>   **daist**, d.h. durchweg nur in Beziehung auf ein Anderes, das
>   Vorstellende, welches er selbst ist.
>
> [...]
>
> Keine Wahrheit ist also gewisser, von allen andern unabhängiger und
>   eines Beweises weniger bedürftig, als diese, daß Alles, was für die
>   Erkenntniß **daist**, also die ganze Welt, nur Objekt in Beziehung auf das
>   Subjekt ist, Anschauung des Anschauenden, mit Einem Wort, Vorstellung.

Aus *Die Welt als Wille und Vorstellung, Band 1*, Seite 16. Siehe Link oben.

Comment: Wie läutet diese Wörter in den verschiedenen Übersetzungen? Das könnte einen Hinweisgeben, ob dies ortographisch oder philosofisch bedingt ist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Schopenhauers Werk *»[Die Welt als Wille und Vorstellung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Welt_als_Wille_und_Vorstellung)«* ist 1819 erschienen. Die *»[Konferenz zur Herstellung größerer Einigung in der deutschen Rechtschreibung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1876)«*, später auch *»Erste Orthographische Konferenz«* genannt, war die allerste Vereinheitlichung der deutschen Rechtschreibung, und sie fand erst 1876, also 57 nach Erscheinen des Werks statt.

Man kann also durchaus sagen, dass Schopenhauer sich mit seiner Orthographie noch in einer unreglementierten Ära befand. Vieles war zwar durch den gängigen Gebrauch in eine Art Quasi-Norm gebracht worden, aber es gab noch keine wirklich handfesten Rechtschreibregeln.

Das führte dazu, dass so gut wie jeder Autor sich das Recht herausnahm, das was er schrieb, so niederzuschrieben, wie er es für richtig hielt. Und offenbar hielt es Schopenhauer damals für angebracht, an einigen Stellen *da* und *ist* zu einem Wort zusammenzufügen. Ganz einfach, weil er damals damit noch gegen keine Regel verstieß. (Kafka schrieb z.B. das Wort *»ging«* (*Er ging fort*) immer mit langem i (*Er gieng fort*))

Was genau Schopenhauer dazu bewegt hat, wissen wir heute nicht genau. Wir können nur vermuten, und deine philosophisch angelegte Vermutung ist sicherlich eine mögliche Art, das zu erklären zu versuchen.

Es könnten aber auch dutzende andere Gründe zutreffen. Vielleicht war es damals auch üblich, die beiden Wörter beim Sprechen zusammenzuziehen, was Schopenhauer vielleicht im Schriftbild wiedergeben wollte. Wir wissen es schlichtweg nicht. Wir können Schopenhauer nicht mehr fragen.

Dies hier ist ein Forum der deutschen Sprache, kein Philosophie-Forum. Daher findet meine Antwort an diesem Punkt auch ein Ende. Aus sprachlicher Sicht gibt es dazu nicht viel mehr zu sagen.

Comment: Es könnte auch sein, dass er „dasein“ als ein Wort (als Verb, nicht als Nomen „Dasein“) betrachtet und demzufolge die Konjugation zusammengeschrieben hat.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn Du dir die Erstausgabe anschaust: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=S15dAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ViewAPI&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=da%20ist&f=false
so kannst Du feststellen, dass Schopenhauer tatsächlich „nur als Vorstellung da ist“ schrieb. Den Beschluss, „daist“ als einzelnes Wort zu drucken, muss man dem Herausgeber der von Dir benutzten Ausgabe anlasten. Für Schopenhauer, wie für die moderne Orthographie, wird das Nomen „Dasein“ als einzelnes Wort, das Verbum „da sein“ als zwei Wörter geschrieben.